# SSRS Keep page header on top of page when scrolling

Tags: reporting-services

Alright, I know how to keep the Row Headers fixed when scrolling. I want to know how to keep PAGE header fixed when scrolling. The Tablix has no header. The page header will act as the Tablix header.

I have tried the Tablix header and it would not work when the report is exported to Excel. I read that the Page header WILL work. I am going to recreate my Tablix header as my Page header and align it just right so it looks like its a Tablix header.

When I create a new report and paste my query, it automatically creates a tablix. Once I remove the Tablix header and create a new page header, all my (static) groups are gone. I cannot set the property anywhere. How do I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're out of luck. The page header is a completely separate section of the rdl. Just as static groups are (intrinsically) part of a tablix.